# Persist a reference in ASP.NET web site

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

We have VS2010, ASP.NET 4.0 web site (not web project). Multiple developers work on it. I need this site to reference AjaxControlToolkit.dll. So, I checked in AjaxControlToolkit.dll into source control, then right-clicked on the web site, went to Property Pages, References, clicked Add, then added AjaxControlToolkit.dll.

As a result of my action, AjaxControlToolkit.dll was copied to BIN folder of the web site. So, all works fine on my machine. But, I see no record anywhere in the solution or project files that AjaxControlToolkit.dll is referenced from the web site.

Since we don't check in BIN folders or any .user or .suo files into the source control, when another developer gets latest, AjaxControlToolkit.dll is missing from the BIN folder and he/she gets an error until he/she adds the DLL to the BIN folder.

Is there any way to add a DLL reference to a web site and have that reference persisted on different machines?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using an ASP.net WebSite, and not *Web Application* then this is a little more awkward.  If it is an old school Web Site project, then I suggest upgrading it to a Web Application.

Answer (score 3):

At my current company, we create a folder in the project called "ReferencedAssemblies". All external (non .NET) assemblies are located in and referenced from this folder.

This way, you also guarantee that any updates to an external assembly are present whenever a developer performs a "Get Latest" or when the project is deployed.

HTH.

Comment: We have the same setup. My question was about a DLL getting from that "ReferencedAssemblies" folder to the BIN folder in the web site. If you use Add Reference menu, the DLL is copied, but this reference is not reflected in the solution file, so when another dev gets latest, even though they have the DLL in "ReferencedAssemblies", it doesn't exist in BIN and they have to re-add it.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry about that. What are the Reference Paths configured in the project? You want them to point to the "ReferencedAssemblies" folder **not** the bin folder (or not set which is the default). This will tell the project to look in that folder first when compiling the project.

Comment: I cannot find where to set Reference Paths for a Web Site project in VS2010? Can you please explain how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: We do not have the Web Site project installed on our machines, only Web Applications, but I think it is basically the same. Right-click on the project, click "Properties", then there **should** be a tab titled "References". From there you should be able to add the path to your assemblies. Let me know if you find it.

Comment: @ShaiCohen Web sites don't have project files and project files are where references are stored so this will not work unless they switch to using web application projects rather than web sites.

Comment: @alhalama: Thanks for clarifying that. I haven't used them for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Web sites don't have project files which is where you would typically find references so you will not be able to reference the assembly other than having it in the bin of the web site or in the GAC of the machine where the site is running.

The only references that you will find to assemblies in a web site are the add assembly tags in the web.config, the register tags in pages and user controls, and the licenses.licx file if you are using controls that require licensing such as Infragistics.

Your options are to either set up all of the development machines to already have the assembly or to use a WebApplicationProject so that you can add a folder with the assemblies and add the references to the project with either a hint path set or a reference path set in your project so that visual studio can find the assembly.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the referenced DLL in a 'References' directory that is source controlled then  put the relative path to it inside a [dll name].refresh file in the website's /bin folder.  Also source control the .refresh file.

Everytime Visual Studio compiles your ASP.NET website, it'll use the .refresh file to find the DLL in the 'References' directory and copy it to your /bin folder.

So for example, if your website references ThirdParty.dll,  Set up your structure like so:

```
\References
    \ThirdParty.dll
\MySite
    \bin
       \ThirdParty.dll.refresh
```

Then in ThirdParty.dll.refresh have this line

```
../../References/ThirdParty.dll
```